Hide a row if a textbox containing a subreport is blank
I am writing a report with a table that contains a column with a subreport in it. If the subreport returns a NULL, then I want to hide the row from the report when run. I have tried the following statements in the visibility property of the row. Neither work and return the same error.
=iif(isnothing(ReportItem!Textbox44.Value), True, False)
=iif(trim(ReportItem!Textbox44.Value) = "", True, False)
Error message: the hidden expression for the tablix "Details" contains an error. The expression references the report item "Textbox44" which does not exist in the ReportItems collection...
I have used this technique for hiding row based on field values, but in this case, I'm trying to hide the row if the textbox containing the subreport is blank.
TIA, Kevin
